# How to get the structure of a record in PL/SQL while running a procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, record

Suppose i have a file with structure as:

```
Declare
    type file_type is record
    (
        field1 number(10),
        field2 char,
        field3 varchar(50),
        field4 number(50),
        ..
        ..
        field100 varchar(50),
    )

    file_rec file_type;
BEGIN
    /*  1)  Here we will get data from some tables/views and then prepare
            record for file "file_rec".
        2)  Once i have all the fileds file_rec.field1 to.. 
            file_rec.field100 is ready,
            we need to write the record in file.
        3)  while writing i have to pass all the fields to DBMS_OUTPUT package/ prepare a string 
            after concatinating all the fileds.(I dont want to pass this.I hate this).
        4)  So i want to create a procedure lets say PROC_WRITE(file_rec) which will take only 
            file_rec as input and it will then find the structure of file_rec and 
            then will prepare a string with proper padding and write it to a different file.
        5)  Note: 
            a)  PROC_WRITE will be a generic function, which should be able to take any record structure as input.
            b)  All the file record structure will be inside different procedure(which are inside different pacakges).
                It means record structures are not on schema level.
    */
END;
```

Let me know if we have any better solution for this. Just a condition that function should be generic.
Thanks,
Pravin

Comment: You've just created the record; don't you already know the datatypes, meaning you could hard code it in your procedure?

Comment: From your description I am guessing you are trying to make this generic so that if the type changes you do not need to change your function? If so then I would declare your type outside your package, then you are able to use DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl or DBMS_METADATA.get_XML to get the structure of your type and dynamically output all fields to your file. (see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66885 for documentation on DBMS_METADATA)

Comment: Your record structure will not change at runtime, so your code to format the data for output will not need to change at runtime either; it does not need to be dynamic.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, I was not talking about run time changes.  My interpretation of the question is that the fields in the type might change due to business requirements.  So if / when this happens only the type would need to change, not the code that outputs the file.

Comment: That's exactly my point. If the only time the code needs to change is when you are changing the code, *you can change the code* - it doesn't need to be dynamic.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, i have updated the question. Please let me know if it clarifies your doubts. i need something similar to what @ShaunPeterson. so that it works for objects which are not defined on schema level.